# waitgroup.Wait() causing dead lock

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I'm trying to figure out why I have a dead lock with waitgroup.Wait()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func foo(c chan int, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- i
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go foo(ch, i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
    for item := range ch {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

When I run it like this, it prints `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

I tried to change `ch` to a buffered channel and that solved the problem. But I really want to know why is there a dead lock.

Comment: It happens because none of your `wg.Done()` is called, because your `foo` calls never return. They don't return because there is nothing to read from `ch` so `c <- i` is blocked forever. You need to put both `wg.Wait() + close(ch)` into their own separated goroutine. https://play.golang.org/p/JbQqVyZPqQ_U

Comment: After the deadlock message, the error output should show you where each goroutine is waiting.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you @zerkms ! If I understand correctly from your playground example: the while different go routine are going on, the for loop in main are consuming the value from `ch` so they are not blocked anymore. The moment wg is done waiting, it will close the channel and therefore stop the loop in main routine.

Comment: @AlexXu exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've commented out the parts where your program's logic is not correct:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func foo(c chan int, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- i
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int) // unbuffered channel

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go foo(ch, i)
    }

    // wg.Wait is waiting for all goroutines to finish but that's
    // only possible if the send to channel succeeds. In this case,
    // it is not possible as your receiver "for item := range ch" is below
    // this. Hence, a deadlock.
    wg.Wait()

    // Ideally, it should be the sender's duty to close the channel.
    // And closing a channel before the receiver where the channel
    // is unbuffered is not correct.
    close(ch)

    for item := range ch {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

Corrected program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func foo(c chan int, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- i
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for item := range ch {
            fmt.Println(item)
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go foo(ch, i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}
```

Comment: Good answer! FWIW, I usually find it clearer to put the output or aggregation logic (in this case the `fmt.Println` calls) in the main goroutine, and to use closures instead of top-level functions for the work associated with a `sync.WaitGroup`. Folding in those (relatively minor) changes: https://play.golang.org/p/iBo4V8eKGtx

Comment: Yep, agreed @bcmills!

Comment: why putting `receiver` or `close(ch)` in the separated goroutine would avoid deadlock?

Comment: @TomSawyer Sender should never close the channel. You can see that there are multiple sender goroutines but sending to close channel causes a panic; so any sender should not ever close the channel as there might be other senders who are still sending data to the channel. Now we are closing `ch` after `wg.Wait` because we want the receiver to receive all the data sent by the senders, i.e., `for item := range ch ` loops and receives until the channel is closed and we ensure the closing of the channel after the receiver completes its job because of the reason above. Clear?